# How do you use the FindRecord method in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a small query builder on a form I created that allows the user to save the query they built. Works great! Then I realized that they can save multiple queries using the same name. Not good. What I'm doing is when they build the query and choose to save it, I just add the SQL string to a table in one field and a name, that they choose, in another field. Easy enough. So now I figure all I have to do search the Name field and check it against the name the user has chosen. I dont know why, but I cant seem to wrap my mind around it. I can't seem to get the FindRecord to work. Does it return a boolean? Can't I just do something like this...

```
If DoCmd.FindRecord(userNameVariable) = True Then
 msgbox("That name exists") 
Else
 msgbox(That name doesnt exist)
End If
```

Now that I look at that, it doesn't give any where to look, such as the table and field name.

Answer (score 1):

DoCmd.FindRecord returns the first record found with that criteria. If you only want to check if that name already exists I think that there is a better way to do what you need.

One way  is to build a SQL string like 
`"SELECT [Name] FROM [Table] WHERE [Name] = '" & userNameVariable & "'"`, 
execute the Query and then test if the recordset is empty. The Code would look like

```
Dim rs as recordset
Dim strSQL as string
strSQL = "SELECT [Name] FROM [Table] WHERE [Name] = '" & userNameVariable & "'"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then 
   msgbox "This Query name already exists, please select another" 
End If
```

Comment: That is beautiful! Ill give it a try. I dont use record sets very often, only because I just dont know how, but the more I read, the more I see it seems to be the best way of doing things. Thank you for your help, its truely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835361.aspx), it simply goes to the data you searched for.  I don't think that's what you need.

Here's what I would do (I'm not saying it's the best method, just what I would do).  Assuming the table is called `TblName` and the field holding the saved name is `SQLName` then:

```
If CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
    "Select count(*) from TblName where SQLName='" & SQLName & "';") _
    .Fields(0) > 0 Then
    'Do Something
End If
```

Comment: Very nice, I will try this also. I enjoy learning different ways to do something. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help.  @kbsou's answer and mine effectively do the same thing.  Mine is more compact, but not necessarily as readable.

Answer (score 0):

Saved query names are stored in the unsupported MSysObjects table, so in a local database you can look up that table to find if a query exists:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("name", "msysobjects", "name='" _
    & qryname & "' and type=5")) Then

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(qryname, sSQL)
Else
   MsgBox qryname " already exists."
End If
```